# No funciona el enviar form

Tags: php, html

Dado este código, a veces me funciona el enviar y otras veces no, lo pongo https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_scripts_intro
o algun otro editor y si envia, pero en mi localhost no, estoy con xampp. Tiene el form action=resultado.php pero nada, no me envia el boton submit

```
    <form action="resultado.php" method="post">  
    Mensaje a descifrar
        <select name="opciones" id="opciones" onchange="mostrarInput();">
            <option value="" selected disabled>----------</option>
            <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
            <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
            <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
            <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
            <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
            <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
            <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
        <input name="number" id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>

         <!–  Borrar los valores ->
        <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

        <!–  Recoger los datos ->
        <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

    </form>
    <script src="funcion.js">
    </script>
```

**funcion.js**

```
//seleccionando elementos
    var inputDate = document.getElementById('date');
    var inputNumero = document.getElementById('numero');
      var select = document.getElementById('opciones');

    //ocultar input fecha y numero
    inputDate.style.display = "none";
    inputNumero.style.display = "none";

  function mostrarInput(){
      var valorSeleccionado = select.value;
    if(valorSeleccionado == 'dateDecToRoman'){
            //ocultar input numero en caso de estar mostrandolo
        inputNumero.style.display = "none";
          //mostrar input fecha
        inputDate.style.display = "block";
    }else{
            //ocultar input fecha en caso de estar mostrandolo
        inputDate.style.display = "none";
          //mostrar input numero
        inputNumero.style.display = "block";
    }

  }// end function mostrarInput
```

Comment: Y en tu código `resultado.php`, cómo estás obteniendo los datos? O lo quieres enviar mediante JS?

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta seleccionar el input desde JS, yo agregaria un ID al input

```js
 'use strict'



    var inputDate = document.getElementById('date');
        var inputNumero = document.getElementById('numero');
        var select = document.getElementById('opciones');

 

    $("submit").submit(function mostrarInput(){
        var valorSeleccionado = select.value;
        if(valorSeleccionado == 'dateDecToRoman'){
                
            inputNumero.style.display = "none";
              
            inputDate.style.display = "block";
        }else{
                
            inputDate.style.display = "none";
              
            inputNumero.style.display = "block";
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">  
        Mensaje a descifrar
            <select name="opciones" id="opciones" onchange="mostrarInput();">
                <option value="" selected disabled>----------</option>
                <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
                <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
                <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
                <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
                <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
                <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
                <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
            <input name="number" id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>

             <!–  Borrar los valores ->
            <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

            <!–  Recoger los datos ->
           
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar">

        </form>
        <script src="funcion.js">
        </script>
```

Comment: pero no te oculta lo que es date y el input

Comment: Am creo que no lo coloque en el código puedes personalizar el código para que haga lo que necesitas